# Wordpresson GCP VM very slow after install

Tags: wordpress, performance, google-cloud-platform

I'm playing around with GCP VMs for my wordpress site but am having some problems.

Installed wordpress with Click to Deploy from the marketplace. This install was working fine but was broken by Updraftplus. So I've stopped it by clicking stop.

I've now installed Wordpress on a new 2nd VM and moved the reserved IP address to the 2nd VM.

However when I try to access the site with its domain name or IP address its extremely slow and i cant login to admin.

In monitoring everything is within its limits and my qoutas look fine.

Any help provided will be much appreciated as I'd really like to learn how to use a VM on GCP so I can use it for my proper website and be able to solve any problems I might encounter.

Thanks
Stephen

- why is my 2nd install of wordpress click to deploy running so slow ?

Comment: 1) Your question lacks specific details on a problem. **slow** and **cannot login** are not problem descriptions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 2) The first step is to document the system configuration. Then review the system and Apache log files for problems. Create tests that reproduce problems and analyze the results. Update your question with one problem with details.

Comment: WordPress (LAMP) is very easy to deploy. I recommend that you configure Compute Engine yourself and not use click to deploy. Bitnami uses its (very different) convention for configuration that will cause challenges for you trying to solve problems.

Comment: great thanks i'll try following the LAMP tutorial.

Comment: I followed some tutorials to install LAMP and then wordpress and its been very educational and this wordpress looks to not have the problems of click to deploy.  Thanks for your help, I can move my main site to GCP now with confidence that its all working OK.

Comment: I recommend installing one of the WordPress firewalls such as WordFence. Hackers love to pick on WordPress installations. Also, lock down SSH access (port 22) to your IP address.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into WP firewalls and locking down ssh access though I think I remember selecting an option restricting ssh access.